# SQL Server Reporting Services - FQDN you are not allowed to view this folder

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I can access to reporting service by http://hostname/reports

Because i want to implement SSL certificate, i need to configure SSRS to work with FQDN

so in Reporting Server Configuration Manager for Web portl URL i set Host Header name, same for Web Services URL

[image]

Then configured service account (under which SSRS is running) as per https://blog.andycook.com/sql/2019/11/13/ssrs-fqdn/

When trying to login with service account i'm getting, credentials pop-up, after entering credentials then getting:

to http://host.example.com/reports

[image]

**Edit:**

After adding service account to local admin group then using that account i can see all reports. When loging in with other user who's not local admin, cannot see reports

Comment: Don't suppose you changed the server's name while you were reconfiguring things? The User table in the ReportServer database contains the Windows account names of users, including the server/domain name. If you changed the server/domain name then your user logins will no longer match those stored in the User table, so they'll lose their previously assigned permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it, once i logged in with service account (which i added to local admin group), i just clicked home-manage security and added users